# Live Unwrap is turned off but adding seams unwraps the whole mesh (blender 2.93.4)

Tags: uv

As I wrote above live unwrap feature is turned off but adding or deleting seams causes mesh to instantly re-unwrap. Can someone explain to me how to fix it?

Comment: Even turned on, live-unwrap shouldn't do anything when you add/remove seams. Do you use any addon (like UV Toolkit, Textools or whatever) ?

Comment: Yeah, I use them

Comment: Ok so maybe the problem is related to one of this addons. I may be wrong, but I can't see nothing in vanilla Blender that can cause this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in *Edit Mode*, on the *Properties Editor > Active Tool* and workspace settings, under options is there a *Live Unwrap* checkbox. This is not synced with the *UV Menu > Live Unwrap* checkbox. So make sure both are turned off.

[image]